# Android VLC sdk 2.1.12 streaming problems with SurfaceView

Tags: android, sdk, surfaceview, vlc, libvlc

So I'm working on integrating the updated VLC SDK 2.1.12 into my test application and there are a few problems:

Here is what I included in my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
`dependencies{
.....
compile 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'
}`
```

I've created a class that hosts the necessities i've found in other demos in Github, called VlcBasePlayer.java

**VlcBasePlayer**

```
public class VlcBasePlayer implements IVLCVout.Callback {

private SurfaceView mSurface;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Context mActivity;
private LibVLC libvlc;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
private MediaPlayer.EventListener mPlayerListener = new VlcBasePlayer.MyPlayerListener(this);
private final static String TAG = "VlcBasePlayer";

public VlcBasePlayer(Context context, SurfaceView surfaceView, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
    this.mSurface = surfaceView;
    this.mHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.mActivity = context;
}

public void createAndPlay(String url) {
    releasePlayer();
    try {

        // Create LibVLC
        libvlc = new LibVLC(mActivity);
        mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        // Create media player
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
        mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(mPlayerListener);

        // Set up video output
        final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
        vout.setVideoView(mSurface);
        Log.d(TAG,"sheight: " + mSurface.getHeight() +  " swidth: " + mSurface.getWidth());
        //vout.setSubtitlesView(mSurfaceSubtitles);
        vout.addCallback(this);
        vout.attachViews();
        //vout.setWindowSize(((Activity)mActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth(), ((Activity)mActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight());
        Media m = new Media(libvlc, Uri.parse(url));
        mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
        mMediaPlayer.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Error creating player!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating player");
    }
}

public void releasePlayer() {
    if (libvlc == null)
        return;
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
    vout.removeCallback(this);
    vout.detachViews();
    libvlc.release();
    libvlc = null;
}

@Override
public void onSurfacesCreated(IVLCVout vlcVout) {

}

@Override
public void onSurfacesDestroyed(IVLCVout vlcVout) {

}


private class MyPlayerListener implements MediaPlayer.EventListener {
    private WeakReference<VlcBasePlayer> mOwner;

    MyPlayerListener(VlcBasePlayer owner) {
        mOwner = new WeakReference<>(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(MediaPlayer.Event event) {
        VlcBasePlayer player = mOwner.get();

        switch (event.type) {
            case MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached:
                player.releasePlayer();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Playing:
                Log.d(TAG, "player playing");
                if(mActivity instanceof MenuTVGuide){
                    MenuTVGuide.hideLoadingStreamProgressbar();
                }
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Paused:
                Log.d(TAG,"player paused");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Stopped:
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Buffering:
                //Log.d(TAG, "player buffering");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

With the line that I have commented out: -> `vout.setWindowSize(((Activity)mActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth(), ((Activity)mActivity).getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight());`

If I would uncomment that line above in a separate project with just a surfaceview inside its frame layout parent, the video stream seems to show well (as if it is fitted inside the surfaceview while keeping aspect ratio)

But if I would comment that out, then the stream would look like it has been zoomed in on and I can't see the full aspect ratio of it.

In the real application in testing, My layout has a `RelativeLayout` with a surfaceview inside it.This relative layout takes up about 1/3 of the screen in portrait and in the landscape, it is fullscreen.

Now, if I uncomment out the line, this is what happens to what the user sees on the screen
[image]

as you can see, only about 1/10th of the surface view shows the actual stream.
Now if I comment it out, this is what shows(it is zoomed in)

[image]

it is supposed to look like this, as you can see, the logo at the bottom left corner is shown:
[image]

I want my stream to fit the size of my surface view, keep its aspect ratio and fit in different screen orientations

Thanks in advance.